# How make userscript to not download already existing file

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I use tampermonkey on mobile firefox. In userscript I use `GM_download(url, name)` to download file from url. When it start download same file in firefox the result of this is :

Hello.txt

Hello(1).txt

...

Hello(9).txt

I want to know how not download duplicates. Or way to block firefox download duplicate.

Or get directory list. If there file alredy exist dont download.
 In bash(linux cml) you write `ls` ,in windows you write `dir`. But how it would be in userscript? If yo write `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Hello.txt` in your browser it show all files that you want (in this address is Hello.txt file). But I can't get this html or whatever is this via `XMLHttpRequest`

Ps: Sorry for my english

Comment: There's no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the filesystem to check if some file exists. That would be pretty dangerous for userscripts - imagine you installed userscript that did that. Firefox doesn't even allow plugins to access filesystem AFAIK, so tampermonkey cannot provide that API.

What you can do is to remember the name of the downloaded file. Your options are:

- `localStorage` - for example set `localStorage[filename]=true` and then check for that. But if you delete the file on your phone, this will prevent you from downloading it again
- `indexedDB` this is nicer for saving data, but the problem is same as for local storage.

Comment: You can access the filesystem using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) in browsers that support it. Does Firefox support this API?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I was looking into this just recently and it is not widely supported. Even if it was, you'd need the user to give access to the file every time as far as I understand it (I could be wrong). The filesystem API would give you access to a "virtual" file, not the file that user can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of files downloaded with your user script, but cannot access the directory list I think.